# Cannot log in because of corrupted .bash_profile

Tags: login, profile, system-recovery

I have created a new user account.
I can't access it because of a `.bash_profile` error.
How can I repair this type of error?

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's you who created the account, I'm assuming you have root access on the system.

Log in as root and edit the file, correcting the error.

To correct this as the affected user:

- Some graphical logins provide the ability to choose an alternate login shell. Pick one that is not `bash` and log in, fix the error and log out again.  Then pick `bash` as login shell on the next login.
- If this is a remote system, use

  - `ssh -t user@host vim .bash_profile`, or
  - `ssh -t user@host "sh -c 'vim .bash_profile'"`, edit the file and exit.
  - Alternatively, `ssh user@host mv .bash_profile .bash_profile-broken`, or
  - upload a new `.bash_profile` using `scp` (possibly a corrected version of the one fetched using `scp`).